# contentSize sometimes not working on UIScrollView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have the following hierarchy

```
UITableViewCell
| UIView (cell's contentView)
|   | UIScrollView 
|   |   |UIView 
|   |   |  | some other views
```

I set my the scrollview's contentSize to something larger than the scrollView itself in `AwakeFromNib()` but sometimes it stays at the initial value. (I also do it in `prepareOnReuse()`.

I'm using Autolayout and XCode 7 GM. There is no contraints issues on the Storyboard.

Any idea where the problem could come from ?

Comment: Try setting the scrollView as a subview of the tableViewCell's contentView instead of the cell itself. I'm not sure it's the same issue you're having, but I've had a lot of issues with autoLayout if you don't use the contentView.

Comment: My mistake, it's already the case !